# Android's floating windows coupled with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED fails

Tags: android, user-interface, styles

My app, shows a dialog box to the user before the lock screen. It's a simple Activity that contains DialogFragments (from the support library as this app runs on 2.2+).

Since the actual activity that displayed those dialogs was not a floating window by Android's standards,

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

worked fine.

However, I was thinking I'd use an Activity that looks like a Dialog instead. All the Dialog themes (Holo, etc), though, have this item:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

This, for some reason causes the window flag to be completely ignored. Interestingly, the Activity gets shown after the user unlocks the screen.

Why would this be so, and is there a way around it?

Comment: Suffering from the same issue... Were you able to find any work arounds?

Comment: I ended up sticking with an activity that launches a non cancel-able dialog and completely left keyguard disabling out of my app.

Comment: having same issue, i want to make "transperant" activity visible over lock screen, but seems not possible

Comment: @ShirishHerwade I'm almost certain it's because the keyguard is a secure component only allowing system apps to draw over it.

Comment: @A--C I think not even system apps other than Keyguard can draw anything on lock screen, cause mine is a system app, still not able to show text on lock screen. Please help if you know.

Comment: @ShirishHerwade I stuck with the solution in my [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410972/androids-floating-windows-coupled-with-flag-show-when-locked-fails?noredirect=1#comment18763968_13410972). I have no other ideas regarding this, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suffering from the same issue. The only thing that seems to work in this issue is

```
KeyguardManager  myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
myLock = myKeyGuard.newKeyguardLock("tagName");
myLock.disableKeyguard();
```

Dont forget to use the keyguard permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Comment: It's a deprecated API, but it works somewhat, so it still needs some work to get consistent results. However, this seems the best we can do.

Comment: Very helpful answer.  What a shame that this is deprecated because there is a 'better' way to do what you want, only the 'better' way does not work in every case that the 'worse' way does.

Comment: did anyone find a better solution to use? this  solution does unlock the screen, I want to keep the screen locked and display the dialog like whatsapp message. it seems this is possible because whatsapp do have that