# android FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED not working

Tags: android

I am trying to get my application over the lock screen for some input from user, but unable to
do so.

I have tried the following lines in onCreate as well as onAttachToWindow callbacks but nothing seems to wor

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

I have checked most questions on stackoverflow and they all point to the above mentioned solution.

Do we need to use any permission or am I missing anything.
I am working on a rooted galaxy S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this issue is

[Android's floating windows coupled with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410972/androids-floating-windows-coupled-with-flag-show-when-locked-fails/13666996#13666996)

Cannot use floating window along with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED

Answer (score 3):

Note that your activity should not be a dialog.
I had defined in Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="TestDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
</activity>
```

After I removed the theme, it worked and the activity was displayed over any lock screen.
Maybe you can simulate a dialog with the help of the style `@android:style/Theme.Translucent`.

Comment: Any idea or documentation reference as to why is that?

Comment: Do we Intent to this "TestDialog" Activity from Service !!

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested below is also not working...The only option left for me now is adding permission for disable keygaurd in manifest and using

```
KeyguardManager  myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); myLock = myKeyGuard.newKeyguardLock(); myLock.disableKeyguard();
```

I don't want to add a new permission because that will make my application come in manual updates instead of automatic update. :(

Comment: what is diff between your answer or my answer? your are doing same using code i'm just doing using LayoutParams. place my code on right activity then it will work surely

Comment: if you have any issue then you can read here about all flags http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD

Comment: Your answer is the one which I hope could work as it does not require me to take care of enabling and disabling keyguard and also does not need any permission.
 My answer on the other hand needs a permission added to manifest and do enable and disable manually

Comment: then why you are saying it's not working you can take my answer as reference and google about how we use these flags in Activity for disabling keyguard without any permission

Comment: Actually I had already tried the answer you have suggested before posting the question itself. The problem is this "<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>" if the activity style has  this, The window flags do not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I can confirm that the problem is the dialog theme. It seems that the attribute **android:windowIsFloating** is responsible that a dialog is not shown on top of the lock screen. That attribute is set to `true` in the Holo dialog themes.

But if you derive your Holo dialog theme to an own style like this:

```
<style name="ReminderAlarmDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

the dialog activity will be shown on top of the lock screen.
Only problem: The dialog will then fill the entire screen and thus, it doesn't look very well. So it is not a real solution, only an explanation why dialog themes don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, the solution is remove the `setType` line in your activity. (If you already add that)

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    //getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
}
```