# FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED not working in latest version of 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, lockscreen

The main window of my app sets the FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED and FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD window flags to bring up the app window in front of the usual Android lock screen.  The exact code follows

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

This has worked perfectly ever since ICS on all my devices.  But recently I received two reports from end users that the app was no longer coming up on top of the lock screen.  We finally established that the first user was running Cyanogenmod and had him open a support issue with them.  But the second user is running an absolutely stock OS.  To make things even more interested, he reports that it was working properly when he first installed the 4.4 system update.  But installing the most recent system update broke things.  Since then our app no longer appears on top if the lock screen, but it bumps up immediately as soon as the screen is unlocked.

Technical details...
Mode number: SM-G900P
Android Version:4.4.2
Baseband version: G900PVPU1ANE5
Kernel version: 3.4.0-1750661
dpi@SWDD6020 #1
Fri May 30 21:23:48 KST 2014
Build number: KOT49H.G900PVPU1ANE5
SE for Android status
Enforcing
SEPF_SM-G900P_4.4.2_0016
Fri May 30 21:23:28 2014
Security software version
MDF v1.0 Release 3
VPN v1.4 Release 1

I do not have a phone running 4.4 yet.  I run the app on the latest and greatest 4.4 emulator and did not any problem with it popping up over the lock screen.

Anyone else heard any reports of this?  Any suggestions on what we can do next?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when I was looking for an answer why a notification I was creating was not showing up in front of the lock screen. The code worked for an old 2.3 android device, but it was not working for a new 4.4.4 nexus 5.

In my case it was caused by:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

When I changed that to false, it was fixed. Not sure why this requirement is there and if this is not needed on 4.3 and lower (I only have the old 2.3 device and the 4.4.4 nexus 5 to test stuff on).

-- Edit
Also see this issue, seems there is another workaround
[Android's floating windows coupled with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410972/androids-floating-windows-coupled-with-flag-show-when-locked-fails)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't checked on this for a while.  After going round and round about this problem, we eventually concluded that the Android system was doing everything it was supposed to.  The real problem was the 4.4 change disabling our ability to block incoming SMS messages from getting to the default message app.  Our app picked up the incoming SMS message and popped up on top of the lock screen, as intended.  But then the default message app picks up the message and pops up on top of our app window.  Since our app is no longer visible, the lock screen is, quite properly, reinstated.